# BabylonJS GUI Element has strange effects with depthOfField

Tags: babylonjs

Using `BABYLON.DefaultRenderingPipeline` with `depthOfField` creates strange effects on GUI (partly blurred).

[image]

Example:
https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#USTXX4

EDIT:

BABYLON.DynamicTexture https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#USTXX4#2
The workaround I`m going with.

Answer (score 0):

No real solution except having a plane right behind the plane.

BABYLON.DynamicTexture https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#USTXX4#2 The workaround I`m going with.